# SOLR XML Import combining multiple children

Tags: xml, solr, dataimporthandler, pubmed

I'm attempting to load XML into Solr using the DataImportHandler, and have no problems getting data in, but need help transforming the format.   I have tried everything I can think of and googled for possible solutions, and am really stuck.  The source XML looks like this:

```
<AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
  <Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Mohammed</LastName>
    <ForeName>Arshed Abdulhamed</ForeName>
    <Initials>AA</Initials>
  </Author>
  <Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Haris</LastName>
    <ForeName>Sallehuddin Mohamed</ForeName>
    <Initials>SM</Initials>
  </Author>
  <Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Nuawi</LastName>
    <ForeName>Mohd Zaki</ForeName>
    <Initials>MZ</Initials>
  </Author>
</AuthorList>
```

And I would like to end up with something like this:

```
<str name="Author_1">Arshed Mohammed</str>
<str name="Author_2">Sallehuddin Mohamed Harris</str>
<str name="Author_3">Mohd Zaki Nuawi</str>
```

I'm thinking some combination of DIH's ScriptTransformer , TemplateTransformer, and Schema.xml's "dynamicField" would do the trick, but I'm really hitting a wall.  Has anyone else run into a problem like this?

Thank you so very much in advance.